# Smooth shading gets ignored in cycle render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

While working on a Model I stumbled upon this issue:
[image]

This is the first time I see this error and I couldn't find any immediate solution.

I checked if there is any sort of modifier or condition on the mesh which could result to this.

I found nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your blend file or show more about your material nodes setup and eventual modifiers ?

Comment: it could be a problem with the modifier stack, if you don't feel comfortable posting the .blend, you could post a screen shot. Also, make sure the pony's saddle is selected when inspecting the object properties. In the photo, only the pony is selected

Comment: http://puu.sh/pl6M4/c47b131979.zip
This is the edited file~ Its derigged so you can change or use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what it is, but the problem comes from the "use subdivision" in the "displacement panel" here.
At the bottom of the picture below, just uncheck "use subdivision".

[image]