# My object is smooth in solid view but not in rendered mode

Tags: rendering

In solid view, my object's smooth however in render mode it's not. What's the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the Blender file?

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55417/smooth-shading-gets-ignored-in-cycle-render

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Maybe try entering Edit mode, select all and use W > Shade Smooth to explicitly enable smooth shading (as I see there aren't any modifiers on the object). Increasing amount of geometry is kind of workable (though it works around not solving it completely) but not efficient way

Comment: @MrZak increasing the face count until the faces are smaller than a single pixel is a bit resource intensive, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Just increased value of view in render in subdivision surface modifier

Comment: That would make the faces smaller, but not really solve the issue. I tried to recreate it, but somehow I fail so far.

Comment: it didn't help much that you didn't explain in question about using a subsurf modifier... you just talked about smooth... that is a different thing! You should expand your question adding images/details about your exact  setup, and thus this answer would be more useful to others...

Comment: @Haunt_House I guess the OP used a subsurf high "view" level but low "render" level. But "shading" was solid, not smooth. "smoothing" in 3d viewport was perceived thanks to high (view) subsurf level...

Comment: @m.ardito Could be. Yet the specular lighting artifacts look not very high poly at all. And the outline is identical. I could be wrong. Depends on whether she has pressed the smooth button to the left of the screenshot ( : I couldn't get cycles to stay solid with that enabled so far. Hey Liana. Have you pressed that smooth shading button on the left side of the screenshot while the object is selected?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you could have done: you didn't set the object as "smooth" shading with the toolbox button visible in your images, and you had a subsurf with a low "render" level, like 1 but high "view" level...

This makes the object appear "smooth" (thanks to the subsurf settings)  in the 3d view but "solid" when rendered.

[image]

Comment: You can see in the screenshot the object has no modifiers on it.

Comment: @RayMairlot Liana's answer is "Just increased value of view in render in subdivision surface modifier"... only Liana could explain exactly how that object was set...